# xml Позиция абсолютного

Tags: android

Как в *xml* задать `position absolute`? задача сделать *listview* под кнопкой, наподобие *fab button*.

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_topic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="#E2E6E9"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/contact_list_add_button"
    android:layout_width="65dip"
    android:layout_height="65dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button_shape"
    android:text="Add"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: Используйте RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

думаю будет так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/contact_list_add_button"
    android:layout_width="65dip"
    android:layout_height="65dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button_shape"
    android:text="Add"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_topic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:divider="#E2E6E9"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
</ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: вапрос : кнопка над listview но после того как listview полный кнопка пропадает в чем проблема ? и тайна ли в xml добавить код fixed ?

Comment: @DavidKern Это может из за перерисовки. А в стандартном Android Studio, шаблон с картой есть готовый пример, как поставить кнопку над картой. Может тоже поможет

Comment: спасибо    :) @#$%^